# JAVA - WELD Decorator error

Tags: java, decorator, weld

I try to make an Decorator in weld, but weld was return an error. I can't understand what's my error. I used the same example of weld *"weld-se-numberguess"* and i was created an decorator  extends game.

```
 Set 18, 2015 3:41:02 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
 INFO: WELD-000900: 2.2.16 (Final)
 Set 18, 2015 3:41:03 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
 INFO: WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
 Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001455: Decorator [class org.jboss.weld.environment.se.example.numberguess.GameDecorator] decorates [] with delegate type [Game] and delegate qualifiers [@Default] does not declare any decorated types.
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDecorator(Validator.java:570)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$3.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$3.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:94)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

GameDecorator.java

```
@Decorator
public abstract class GameDecorator extends Game implements Serializable {

    @Delegate
    @Inject
    Game game;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9155583141751623258L;

    // public GameDecorator(@Delegate @Any Game game) {
    // }

    @Override
    public int getNumber() {
        return 98;
    }
}
```

bean.xml

```
<beans
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd" bean-discovery-mode="all">
           <decorators>
               <class>org.jboss.weld.environment.se.example.numberguess.GameDecorator</class>
           </decorators>
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you add the decorated bean of type game?

Answer (score 5):

It's an old question, but since I have just faced the same issue let me answer it.

It seems that there is a need for an interface to exist in the class hierarchy. Just try to extract an interface out of your Game class and make both your Game'ish class and the GameDecorator implement it.
Weld documentation says:

> A decorator is a bean (possibly even an abstract class) that
>   implements the type it decorates and is annotated @Decorator.